# How can I animate changes to an @ObservedObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My view is determined by state stored in a `ViewModel`. Sometimes the view might call a function on its `ViewModel`, causing an asynchronous state change.

How can I animate the effect of that state change in the `View`?

Here's a contrived example, where the call to `viewModel.change()` will cause the view to change colour.

- Expected behaviour: slow dissolve from blue to red.
- Actual behaviour: immediate change from blue to red.

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var color: UIColor = .blue

    func change() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.color = .red
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Color(viewModel.color).onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                self.viewModel.change()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `ViewModel` and store the state in the view itself, everything works as expected. That's not a great solution, however, because I want to encapsulate state in the `ViewModel`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var color: UIColor = .blue

    var body: some View {
        Color(color).onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                    self.color = .red
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first code example with the the view model actually slowly faded/dissolved from blue to red as you intend, when I tested with iOS 13.3, Xcode 11.3. Is there any other parent view, or other code that could be influencing this in your project?

Comment: @Seb, you're absolutely right, my bad. I've updated the example so that it better reflects what's going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though using `withAnimation` inside an async closure causes the color not to animate, but instead to change instantly.

Either removing the wrapping `asyncAfter`, or removing the `withAnimation` call and adding an `animation` modifier in the `body` of your `ContentView` (as follows) should fix the issue:

```
Color(viewModel.color).onAppear {
    self.viewModel.change()
}.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
```

Tested locally (iOS 13.3, Xcode 11.3) and this also appears to dissolve/fade from blue to red as you intend.

Comment: Yep, this does the trick. I suppose the fact that `viewModel.change` is async must break `withAnimation { ... }`, which makes sense I guess. I'd still rather have an explicit animation on a call to `viewModel.doSomething()`, rather than an implicit animation modifier, but beggars can't be choosers!

Comment: if you agree with my assessment that the async update is the real cause of the problem, it might be worth updating your answer for any future Googlers. If not I'd be happy to do make the edit myself :)

Comment: Yep, agreed on that assessment. Edited my answer, but open to yourself or anyone else to further reword/tweak as needed :)

Answer (score 52):

## Using .animation()

You can use `.animation(...)` on a body content or on any subview but it will animate all changes of the view.

Let's consider an example when we have two API calls through the ViewModel and use `.animation(.default)` on body content:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class ArticleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title = ""
    @Published var content = ""

    func fetchArticle() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?.title = "Article Title"
        }
    }

    func fetchContent() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?.content = "Content"
        }
    }
}

struct ArticleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ArticleViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if viewModel.title.isEmpty {
                Button("Load Article") {
                    self.viewModel.fetchArticle()
                }
            } else {
                Text(viewModel.title).font(.title)

                if viewModel.content.isEmpty {
                    Button("Load content...") {
                        self.viewModel.fetchContent()
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                } else {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(height: 80)
                        .overlay(Text(viewModel.content))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        .animation(.default) // animate all changes of the view
    }
}
```

The result would be next:

[image: Animation modifier on body]

You can see that we have animation on both actions. It might be preferred behavior but in some cases, you may want to **control each action** separately.

## Using .onReceive()

Let say we want animate the view after first API call (`fetchArticle`), but on the second (`fetchContent`) - just redraw view without animation. In other words - animate the view when the `title` received but does not animate view when the `content` received.

To implement this we need:

1. Create a separate property `@State var title = ""` in the View.
2. Use this new property all over the view instead of
   `viewModel.title`.
3. Declare `.onReceive(viewModel.$title) { newTitle in ... }`. This closure will execute when the publisher (`viewModel.$title`) sends a new value. On this step, we have control over properties in the View. In our case, we will update the `title` property of the View.
4. Use `withAnimation {...}` inside the closure to animate the changes.

So we will have animation when the `title` updates. While receiving a new `content` value of the ViewModel our View just updates without animation.

```swift
struct ArticleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ArticleViewModel()
    // 1
    @State var title = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // 2
            if title.isEmpty {
                Button("Load Article") {
                    self.viewModel.fetchArticle()
                }
            } else {
                // 2
                Text(title).font(.title)

                if viewModel.content.isEmpty {
                    Button("Load content...") {
                        self.viewModel.fetchContent()
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                } else {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(height: 80)
                        .overlay(Text(viewModel.content))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        // 3
        .onReceive(viewModel.$title) { newTitle in
            // 4
            withAnimation {
                self.title = newTitle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result would be next:

[image: Useing onReceive]

Comment: That's a very thorough and well written answer. Thumbs up!

Comment: The life savior is solution 2, onRecieve is only supported in iOS 14 and upwards, I ended up using PublishedObjects to mutate title property from outside for my solution

Comment: Given that `.animation(...)` will animate every child views, I think `.onReceive` approach might be better preventing unnecessary side effect (unintended animation).

Comment: remark:
if I extract the code in VStack and put them in a ViewBuilder function, and put .animation()  after the call of the ViewBuilder, the animation does not work. Put .animation() inside the ViewBuilder works.

Comment: This method works great! It looks like it's better & safer to put a `@State` variable in the View instead of just grabbing and modifying the `@Published` inside the ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Update @Seb Jachec's answer for Xcode 14.2, to fix the deprecated warning:

```
        Color(viewModel.color)
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.change()
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: viewModel.color)
```